# Proof of logarithm as a limit (Uniform convergence of a particual sequence to exchange integral)

Tags: calculus

I want to prove that: 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n(t^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)=\log(t)$$
without using L'Hôpital. So,

let $f_n(x)=x^{\frac{1}{n}-1}\;\ \forall x\ge 1$ and let $f(x)=x^{-1}\;\ \forall x\ge 1$, then:

---

***Lemma1:*** $\:\ (f_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}\;\ \text{converges uniformly to}\; f$

 (I'm stuck here)

$$\text{Let}\;\ \epsilon >0, \text{lets take}\;\ N=\frac{1}{\epsilon} (\text{figuring out...}),\; \text{then for}\;\ n>N
\Rightarrow\ n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}>\frac{x-1}{x} \frac{1}{\epsilon}
\\
$$

$$\big|x^{\frac{1}{n}-1}-x^{-1}\big|=x^{\frac{1}{n}-1}-x^{-1}<x^{\frac{1}{n}-1}-\frac{1}{n}$$

and here got stuck since the only thing I can do is make $x^{\frac{1}{n}-1}\le 1...$

---

Now, since $\int_1^t x^{\frac{1}{n}-1}dx=nt^{\frac{1}{n}}-n=n(t^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)$, by ***Lemma1*** we get that:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_1^t x^{\frac{1}{n}-1}dx=\int_1^t \lim_{n\to \infty} x^{\frac{1}{n}-1}dx$$

and, thus:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n(t^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_1^t x^{\frac{1}{n}-1}dx=\int_1^t \lim_{n\to \infty} x^{\frac{1}{n}-1}dx=\int_1^t x^{-1}dx=\int_1^t \frac{1}{x}dx=\log(t)$$

I will appreciate if you could let me know if I got it right, wrong (and why) or missed something.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative and simpler approach without using uniform convergence. Using [this answer to your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1525330/72031) it can be proved that the sequence $s_{n}(t) = n(t^{1/n} - 1)$ tends to a limit for all $t > 0$ and hence this limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty}s_{n}(t)$$ defines a function $L(t)$ from $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with the following properties $$L(ab) = L(a) + L(b),\, L(1/a) = -L(a),\, L(1) = 0$$ Further using the inequalities in the linked answer it is easy to show that $$\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{L(1 + t)}{t} = 1$$ from which it follows that the derivative $$L'(t) = \frac{1}{t}$$ and hence $$L(t) = \int_{1}^{t}\frac{dx}{x}$$ See [this post for more details](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-2_10.html).